# Load javascript code only in some pages that hook my php plugin code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

In my wordpress plugin I need some javascript code only in the page that hook my php functions.
I put the javascript code in `/plugin-name/public/js/plugin-name-public.js.`

I used WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate to start my plugin.

```
Public function enqueue_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/plugin-name-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
}
```

The javascript is loaded on every page.

Comment: _"only in the page that hook my php functions"_ - and what exactly does that _mean_, "hook my php functions"?

Comment: Does your plugin expose some shortcodes, functions, actions, filters, or something else?